# sqlalchemy flush() and get inserted id?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to do something like this:

```
f = Foo(bar='x')
session.add(f)
session.flush()

# do additional queries using f.id before commit()
print f.id # should be not None

session.commit()
```

But `f.id` is `None` when I try it. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Can you initialize SA engine with `echo=True`, and see what SQL gets executed at flush-time? What you describe *should* work and give you the id, but may be there's some other issue that results in f.id being None.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Your sample code should have worked as it is. SQLAlchemy should be providing a value for `f.id`, assuming its an autogenerating primary-key column.  Primary-key attributes are populated immediately within the `flush()` process as they are generated, and no call to `commit()` should be required.  So the answer here lies in one or more of the following:

1. The details of your mapping
2. If there are any odd quirks of the backend in use (such as, SQLite doesn't generate integer values for a composite primary key)
3. What the emitted SQL says when you turn on echo

Comment: You're correct, a quick check in the shell shows it populates the primary key field with a value. I'll have to investigate why it was not working in practice.

Comment: Note also, that you may get an `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.` if you use the autoincremented id after a `commit()` call for a shared session of an engine created for `sqlite`. So in this case you even must use the id created with a `flush()` call, but before the `commit()` call.

Answer (score 208):

I've just run across the same problem, and after testing I have found that NONE of these answers are sufficient.

Currently, or as of sqlalchemy .6+, there is a very simple solution (I don't know if this exists in prior version, though I imagine it does):

**session.refresh()**

So, your code would look something like this:

```
f = Foo(bar=x)
session.add(f)
session.flush()
# At this point, the object f has been pushed to the DB, 
# and has been automatically assigned a unique primary key id

f.id
# is None

session.refresh(f)
# refresh updates given object in the session with its state in the DB
# (and can also only refresh certain attributes - search for documentation)

f.id
# is the automatically assigned primary key ID given in the database.
```

That's how to do it.

Comment: This is getting closer to an answer that might work for me but I receive the following error:  InvalidRequestError: Could not refresh instance '<....>'.  It appears after the flush that the instance simply no longer exists.  Appreciate any insight.

Comment: You just saved my ass. I don't think I will ever use the ORM again coming from Django. The flush() command does NOT work as documented IMHO.

Comment: Update, I had to use ```sessionmaker(autoflush=True)```, that combo w/refresh() provided me with the row ID. #grrr

Comment: If you dont understand the difference between `flush()` and `commit()`, here's a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4202016/1252290

Comment: @PlaidFan Instead of `flush()` use `commit()` and right after that - refresh it with `session.refresh(f)`, works for me, and I use SQLAlchemy version `0.6.7`

Comment: Seams version 1.3.1 doesn't need `session.refresh(f)`

Answer (score 39):

Thanks for everybody. I solved my problem by modifying the column mapping. For me, `autoincrement=True` is required.

origin:

```
id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
```

after modified:

```
id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=True)
```

then

```
session.flush()  
print(f.id)
```

is ok!

Comment: The primary key shouldn't be nullable though

Answer (score 11):

The core solution has been mentioned in other much older answers, but this uses newer async API.

with sqlalchemy==1.4 (2.0 style), following seems to work:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

engine = create_async_engine(
        "postgresql+asyncpg://user:pass@localhost/db",
        echo=False,
    )


# expire_on_commit=False will prevent attributes from being expired
# after commit.
async_session = sessionmaker(
    engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession,
)
# default kwarg autoflush=True


async with async_session() as session: 
    async with session.begin(): 
        f = Foo(bar='x')
        session.add(f)
        print(f.id)
        # None

        await session.flush()
        print(f.id)
        # not None
    # commits transaction, closes session
```

Comment: In particular, if you forget to `await` the call to `session.flush` then the ID won't be present (because the flush won't have happened).

Answer (score 11):

The last couple of hours/days/whatever, I was trying to get the above suggestions to work. Initially, I wrote all my insert functions like so:

```
_add = User(id, user_name, email, ...)
```

Where all the items between the round brackets are variables for None, "user a", "a@example.com", ...

This is my User table:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_name = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

SQLAlchemy handles the _add query correctly, as it inserts the record with an autoincremented ID. Also, as should be, no default value is set for the id column.

I have tried all the above options in various ways (with/without commit, with/without flush, with/without refresh, the one before the other, timeouts in between statements, you name it). I even changed the whole app/database interaction a couple of times. But in all occasions, "_add.id" would either return 0, or something like "Instance '' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present."

Just now I thought "*maybe I should write my _add query a bit different, by also defining the column names for the specified table*" like so:

```
_add = User(id=None, user_name=user_name, email=email, etc)
```

To emphasize, note: **id=**, **user_name=**, **email=**, in the _add query.
Now, with the following statements in this order, SQLAlchemy does return the inserted ID!

```
session.add(_add)
print(_add.id)    <-- returns None

session.flush()   <-- does **not** insert record into database, but does increment id,
                      waiting to be committed. Flush may be omitted, because
                      session.commit() unconditionally issues session.flush()*
print(_add.id)    <-- returns incremented id

session.commit()  <-- commit is needed to actually insert record into database
print(_add.id)    <-- returns incremented id
```

Although the answer has been provided, it wasn't clear for me the missing column names in the _add query, and thus my laziness, were the cause of my problems.
I hope this can help someone avoid the same troubleshoot...

[SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#committing)

Answer (score 7):

unlike the answer given by dpb, a refresh is not necessary.
once you flush, you can access the id field, sqlalchemy automatically refreshes the id which is auto generated at the backend

I encountered this problem and figured the exact reason after some investigation, my model was created with id as integerfield and in my form the id was represented with hiddenfield( since i did not wanted to show the id in my form). The hidden field is by default represented as a text. once I changed the form to integerfield with widget=hiddenInput()) the problem was solved.

Comment: As stated only refresh() worked for me.  In doing a data migration I needed the row ID in a loop to populate a FK. I tried every combo of commit,flush, session hacking and refresh() was the only thing that worked. My data is super clean and I am just finding that SQLA is not really that good (having considerable exp in at least 5 major ORMS). Just wrapping on 5+ hours trying to get the row id for a add()->commit()/flush().

Answer (score 2):

my code works like that:

```
f = Foo(bar="blabla")
session.add(f)
session.flush()
session.refresh(f, attribute_names=[columns name that you want retrieve]
# so now you can access the id inserted, for example
return f.id # id inserted will be returned
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem of *missing id values after creating objects* whilst using `bulk_save_objects`.

Luckily the `return_defaults` parameter in `bulk_save_objects` adds all the ids to the objects without having to call `flush` or `commit`.

```py
users: list[User] = [User(user_name=..., email=..., etc) for foo in bar]
session.bulk_save_objects(references, return_defaults=True)
assert users[0].id is not None # User.id is now populated.
```

See SQLAlchemy documentation:
[:param return_defaults: when True, rows that are missing values which
generate defaults, namely integer primary key defaults and sequences,
will be inserted **one at a time**, so that the primary key value
is available.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_save_objects)

Comment: That was really helpful. I was also trying bulk_save_objects.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem with having assigned `0` to id before calling `session.add` method. The id was correctly assigned by the database but the correct id was not retrieved from the session after `session.flush()`.

Answer (score -7):

You should try using `session.save_or_update(f)` instead of `session.add(f)`.

Comment: `save_or_update` has been deprecated since 0.5 or so. `session.add()` should do it.