# SQLAlchemy: what is the difference between session.commit() and session.flush()?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Does anybody know what the main difference between `session.commit()` and `session.flush()` in SQLAlchemy is?

Comment: Which aspect of the documentation ("flushing" and "committing" in http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#flushing) do you find unclear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy: What's the difference between flush() and commit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201455/sqlalchemy-whats-the-difference-between-flush-and-commit)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are some relevant quotes from the [documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#flushing).

**flush**:

> When the `Session` is used with its default configuration, the flush
>   step is nearly always done transparently. Specifically, **the flush
>   occurs before any individual Query is issued, as well as within the
>   `commit()` call before the transaction is committed**.

**commit**:

> `commit()` is used to commit the current transaction. **It always issues
>   `flush()` beforehand to flush any remaining state to the database**; this
>   is independent of the “autoflush” setting. If no transaction is
>   present, it raises an error. Note that the default behavior of the
>   Session is that a “transaction” is always present; this behavior can
>   be disabled by setting `autocommit=True`. In autocommit mode, a
>   transaction can be initiated by calling the `begin()` method.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way I know how to explain what these do is to just show you, using `echo=True`:

```
>>> session.flush()
BEGIN (implicit)
INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)
('alice', None)
>>> session.commit()
COMMIT
>>>
```

`flush()` causes the data to be sent to the database.  `commit()` causes a `COMMIT`, which tells the database to keep the data that was just sent.  As others have stated, `commit()` will also cause a `flush()` to occur, if it's needed.

Answer (score 7):

Straight from [the documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#flushing):

> `commit()` is used to commit the current transaction. It always issues `flush()` beforehand to flush any remaining state to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Although the above answers are correct, the most useful feature of flush is in applying the changes made to the table in the database back into the concerned object in the code. Here is an example,
Suppose you register a user and you want to give back his id,

```
u = User(name,address,phone) #id is autogenerated 
session.add(u)
session.commit() #calls flush beforehand, but we need it after the commit
session.flush() #updates the objects of the session 
print(u.id) #id field of the User object updated after the flush
```

You need not query again to get his id!! Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> **`flush()`** will synchronize your database with the current state of object/objects held in the memory but it does not commit the transaction. So, if you get any exception after `flush()` is called, then the transaction will be rolled back.
>   You can synchronize your database with small chunks of data using `flush()` instead of committing a large data at once using `commit()` and face the risk of getting an `Out Of Memory` exception.
>
> **`commit()`** will make data stored in the database permanent. There is no way you can rollback your transaction once the `commit()` succeeds.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26976077/4115031