# Hibernate: flush() and commit()

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Is it good practice to call `org.hibernate.Session.flush()` separately?

As said in `org.hibernate.Session` docs,

> Must be called at the end of a unit of work, before commiting the transaction and closing the session (depending on flush-mode, Transaction.commit() calls this method).

Could you explain the purpose of calling `flush()` explicitely if `org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()` will do it already?

Comment: You could inject the `sessionFactory` using the `@Transactional` annotation, If you looked into it. You would not need your code to be transactional everywhere then onwards (it requires in some situations though).

Comment: I just came across an interesting situation in my code, I had to merge an entity that already had an id generated from the client app, and then refresh the same entity to get database generated fields such as date created and modified. Without calling session.flush() it would throw an object not found exception because the merge call is ignored sometimes untill the end of the transaction, when I added flush just after the merge call it forces hibernate to do the actual query and then later refreshing the object works because it now exists in the db!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In the Hibernate Manual you can see this example

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(...);
    session.save(customer);
    if (i % 20 == 0) { // 20, same as the JDBC batch size
        // flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Without the call to the flush method, your first-level cache would throw an OutOfMemoryException

[Also you can look at this post about flushing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)

Comment: could you give reference to this article?

Comment: This answer gives a specific case in which it's a good idea to call flush explicitly, but I don't think it addresses the general question of whether one should always do so.

Comment: Hi @KorayTugay. I do not have experience with new versions of hibernate for a long time. But previously without clean you could receive some unexpected results. So I suggest to try different approaches or even check latest documentation

Answer (score 109):

**`flush()`** will synchronize your database with the current state of object/objects held in the memory but it does not commit the transaction. So, if you get any exception after `flush()` is called, then the transaction will be rolled back.
You can synchronize your database with small chunks of data using `flush()` instead of committing a large data at once using `commit()` and face the risk of getting an `OutOfMemoryException`.

**`commit()`** will make data stored in the database permanent. There is no way you can rollback your transaction once the `commit()` succeeds.

Answer (score 62):

One common case for explicitly flushing is when you create a new persistent entity and you want it to have an artificial primary key generated and assigned to it, so that you can use it later on in the same transaction. In that case calling flush would result in your entity being given an id.

Another case is if there are a lot of things in the 1st-level cache and you'd like to clear it out periodically (in order to reduce the amount of memory used by the cache) but you still want to commit the whole thing together. This is the case that [Aleksei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14582029/217324) covers.

Comment: If you want to have access to the generated PK immediately I believe you need to also call `.refresh(...)`

Comment: We can achieve that by simply calling merge() without needing to call flush() right? Merge will persist and return the persisted object back with id populated.

Answer (score 16):

**`flush();`** Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory. It will update or insert into your tables in the running transaction, but it may not commit those changes.

> You need to flush in batch processing otherwise it may give
>   **OutOfMemoryException.**

**`Commit();`** Commit will make the database commit. When you have a persisted object and you change a value on it, it becomes dirty and hibernate needs to flush these changes to your persistence layer. So, you should commit but it also ends the unit of work (`transaction.commit()`).

Answer (score 10):

It is usually not recommended to call flush explicitly unless it is necessary. Hibernate usually auto calls Flush at the end of the transaction and we should let it do it's work. Now, there are some cases where you might need to explicitly call flush where a second task depends upon the result of the first Persistence task, both being inside the same transaction.

For example, you might need to persist a new Entity and then use the Id of that Entity to do some other task inside the same transaction, on that case it's required to explicitly flush the entity first.

```
@Transactional
void someServiceMethod(Entity entity){
    em.persist(entity); 
    em.flush() //need to explicitly flush in order to use id in next statement
    doSomeThingElse(entity.getId());    
}
```

Also Note that, explicitly flushing does not cause a database commit, a database commit is done only at the end of a transaction, so if any Runtime error occurs after calling flush the changes would still Rollback.

Answer (score 5):

By default flush mode is AUTO which means that: "The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state", but most of the time session is flushed when you commit your changes. Manual calling of the flush method is usefull when you use FlushMode=MANUAL or you want to do some kind of optimization. But I have never done this so I can't give you practical advice.

Answer (score 1):

session.flush() is synchronise method means to insert data in to database sequentially.if we use this method data will not store in database but it will store in cache,if any exception will rise in middle we can handle it.
But commit() it will store data in database,if we are storing more amount of data then ,there may be chance to get out Of Memory Exception,As like in JDBC program in Save point topic