# liferay 7 generated code: blob not written to postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, liferay, liferay-service-builder

I followed [this tutorial](http://proliferay.com/liferay-blob-data-concept/) trying to implement file storage in DB for liferay portlet (using liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga5 with PostgreSQL 9.6) . 
Service.xml:

```
<entity name="MyBlob" local-service="true" table="_MY_BLOB_IMP" human-name="My blobs">
    <column name="myBlobId" type="long" primary="true"
        id-type="increment">
    </column>
    <column name="data" type="Blob"></column>
</entity>
```

Portlet.java:

```
long blobId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(MyBlob.class.getName());
MyBlob blob = _myBlobLocalService.createMyBlob(blobid);
blob.setData(blobData);
//_myBlobLocalService.addMyBlob(blob);
MyBlobLocalServiceUtil.addMyBlob(blob);
```

I got error:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.event.NestableFlushEventListener.onFlush(NestableFlushEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:173)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ClassLoaderSession.flush(ClassLoaderSession.java:282)
```

in the code generated by service builder on line "session.flush();":

```
try {
            session = openSession();

            if (myBlob.isNew()) {
                session.save(myBlob);

                myBlob.setNew(false);
            }
            else {
                session.evict(myBlob);
                session.saveOrUpdate(myBlob);
            }
```

```
            session.flush();
```

```
            session.clear();
        }
```

Here is postgres log:

```
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4131-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  execute S_6: select resourcepe0_.resourcePermissionId as resource1_269_, resourcepe0_.mvccVersion as mvccVers2_269_, resourcepe0_.companyId as companyId269_, resourcepe0_.name as name269_, resourcepe0_.scope as scope269_, resourcepe0_.primKey as primKey269_, resourcepe0_.primKeyId as primKeyId269_, resourcepe0_.roleId as roleId269_, resourcepe0_.ownerId as ownerId269_, resourcepe0_.actionIds as actionIds269_, resourcepe0_.viewActionId as viewAct11_269_ from ResourcePermission resourcepe0_ where (resourcepe0_.companyId=$1 )AND(resourcepe0_.name=$2 )AND(resourcepe0_.scope=$3 )AND(resourcepe0_.primKey=$4 )AND(resourcepe0_.roleId=$5 )
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4132-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '20116', $2 = 'Zalacznik', $3 = '1', $4 = '20116', $5 = '20123'
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4133-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  execute S_6: select resourcepe0_.resourcePermissionId as resource1_269_, resourcepe0_.mvccVersion as mvccVers2_269_, resourcepe0_.companyId as companyId269_, resourcepe0_.name as name269_, resourcepe0_.scope as scope269_, resourcepe0_.primKey as primKey269_, resourcepe0_.primKeyId as primKeyId269_, resourcepe0_.roleId as roleId269_, resourcepe0_.ownerId as ownerId269_, resourcepe0_.actionIds as actionIds269_, resourcepe0_.viewActionId as viewAct11_269_ from ResourcePermission resourcepe0_ where (resourcepe0_.companyId=$1 )AND(resourcepe0_.name=$2 )AND(resourcepe0_.scope=$3 )AND(resourcepe0_.primKey=$4 )AND(resourcepe0_.roleId=$5 )
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4134-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '20116', $2 = 'Zalacznik', $3 = '2', $4 = '20143', $5 = '20123'
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4135-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  execute S_6: select resourcepe0_.resourcePermissionId as resource1_269_, resourcepe0_.mvccVersion as mvccVers2_269_, resourcepe0_.companyId as companyId269_, resourcepe0_.name as name269_, resourcepe0_.scope as scope269_, resourcepe0_.primKey as primKey269_, resourcepe0_.primKeyId as primKeyId269_, resourcepe0_.roleId as roleId269_, resourcepe0_.ownerId as ownerId269_, resourcepe0_.actionIds as actionIds269_, resourcepe0_.viewActionId as viewAct11_269_ from ResourcePermission resourcepe0_ where (resourcepe0_.companyId=$1 )AND(resourcepe0_.name=$2 )AND(resourcepe0_.scope=$3 )AND(resourcepe0_.primKey=$4 )AND(resourcepe0_.roleId=$5 )
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4136-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '20116', $2 = 'Zalacznik', $3 = '4', $4 = 'Zalacznik', $5 = '20123'
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4137-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  execute S_10: BEGIN
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4138-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: insert into _ZALACZNIK_BLOB_IMP (zalacznikBlobId) values ($1)
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4139-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '4'
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4140-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  fastpath function call: "lo_creat" (OID 957)
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4141-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  fastpath function call: "lo_open" (OID 952)
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4142-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  fastpath function call: "lowrite" (OID 955)
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4143-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  fastpath function call: "lowrite" (OID 955)
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4144-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  fastpath function call: "lowrite" (OID 955)
(  .  .  .  )
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4179-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  fastpath function call: "lowrite" (OID 955)
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4180-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  fastpath function call: "lo_close" (OID 953)
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4181-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  execute <unnamed>: update _MY_BLOB_IMP set data=$1 where myBlobId=$2
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4182-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '23373', $2 = '204'
2017-11-27 14:55:35 CET [20752]: [4183-1] user=liferay_umsw,db=umswportal,app=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver,client=127.0.0.1 LOG:  execute S_33: ROLLBACK
```

Is the code from example not longer valid for liferay 7, should I implement blobs for postgre in some other manner or am I making some other mistake?

Thanks,

**UPDATE:
removing session.flush() and session.clear() doesn't help, it moves error to commit...**

```
at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortletTransactionManager$TransactionStatusWrapper.reset(PortletTransactionManager.java:260)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortletTransactionManager.commit(PortletTransactionManager.java:63)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor._commit(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:128)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.commit(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:36)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:137)
```

Comment: is there `tx.commit();` method?.. cos in logs all goes OK, and then you just rollback (I assume with `session.flush();`)

Comment: What data type is that column? I wouldn't be surprised if that was `oid` (aka "large object") instead of `bytea` which would be the correct mapping for BLOB. Probably because the underlying obfuscation layer (ORM) already does this incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, it is oid. Need to check if it can be changed to bytea for service builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like problem with your auto-increment.

You can do 2 things

1) Check if your database table (_MY_BLOB_IMP ) is setup for autoincrement.

2) Change your service.xml and remove  id-type="increment" and regenerate services.

and update your code..

> ```
> long blobId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(MyBlob.class.getName());
> MyBlob blob = _myBlobLocalService.createMyBlob(blobid);
> blob.setData(blobData);
> //_myBlobLocalService.addMyBlob(blob);
> MyBlobLocalServiceUtil.addMyBlob(blob);
> ```

Comment: Thanks, table do not have autoincerement, I do have increment line in my code (added to question for clarity). Removing id-type from service.xml does not seem to change anything...

Comment: did you regenerated services after removing id-type?

Comment: No! It works! Sir, You are a genius :)

Should I remove id-type from all my entities or only blob ones?

Other things seem to work ok with this setting...

Comment: yes if your planning use counterlocalservice then remove from all. its always better.

Answer (score 0):

you begin transaction before (I see it in logs)

```
insert into _ZALACZNIK_BLOB_IMP (zalacznikBlobId) values ($1)
```

but later you flush and close session without commiting - that's why you have your changes not svaed in db, try adding commit before `session.close()`

eg if you have

```
Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
```

add

```
tx.commit();
```

[also there some answers related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26976077/5315974)