# Does SQLAlchemy save order when adding objects to session?

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

Does this assert always pass or not?  In other words, does SQLAlchemy save the order (in generating INSERT queries) when adding new objects to session?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base = declarative_base(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
Entity.__table__.create(checkfirst=True)


first = Entity()
session.add(first)

second = Entity()
session.add(second)

session.commit()
assert second.id > first.id
print(first.id, second.id)
```

None, in production I'm using postgresql, sqlite is for testing.

Comment: I can neither find the code in sqlalchemy that causes this to be so (its `dict`s and `set`s in lots of places) nor can I produce a compelling counterexample (short of the non-monotonicity in the sequence), and so +1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After looking a bit at the SQLAlchemy source, it looks like `add()` records when it was inserted: https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L1719

The relevant snippet:

```
def _save_impl(self, state):
    if state.key is not None:
        raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
            "Object '%s' already has an identity - it can't be registered "
            "as pending" % state_str(state))

    self._before_attach(state)
    if state not in self._new:
        self._new[state] = state.obj()
        state.insert_order = len(self._new) # THE INSERT ORDER IS SAVED!
    self._attach(state)
```

And this is called from `Session.add` => `self._save_or_update_state` => `self._save_or_update_impl` => `self._save_impl`.

It's then used in `_sort_states` when saving: https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py#L859

Unfortunately, this is only implementation-level proof. I couldn't find anything in the documentation that guarantees it...

**Update**:
I've since looked a bit more into this, it turns out there's a concept called *Unit of Work* in SQLAlchemy that somewhat defines the order during a flush: http://www.aosabook.org/en/sqlalchemy.html (search for Unit of Work).

Within the same class, the order is indeed determined by the order that `add` was called. However, you may see different orderings in the INSERTs between different classes. If you add object `a` of type `A` and later add object `b` of type `B`, but `a` turns out to have  a foreign key to `b`, you'll see an INSERT for `b` before the INSERT for `a`.

Comment: @zzzeek Is there anyway to to control the ordering of statements in the case there is a circular fk?

Answer (score -3):

No, it does them when you commit, not when you add.

Comment: I knew that queries are sent to db in flush() or commit(). But I guess sqlalchemy generates INSERT queries with the order of session.add() commands. (I tested with the above Entity class and postgres)

Comment: Yes it generates insert queries, but the id (primary key) could be determined by the db, as there could be a trigger that executes on insert which increases the sequence nr and so on.

Comment: The original asker is wondering whether or not the INSERT statements are emitted, upon commit, in the order that they were added. Upvoted, because I'm wondering the same. //Edit: figured it out! Answering in a bit.