# PostgreSQL / SQLalchemy returns id of object but it is not persisted

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, uwsgi

I am using Pyramid, SQLalchemy (with ZopeTransactionExtension), Postgresql and uwsgi and I have a problem with my web app.

So when I save object using `DBSession.add(object)` and flush `DBSession.flush()` I get no error and I even get the id of the newly created object, but when the page reloads I see success message but the object does not appear in the list of all objects. (No error was thrown. In PostgreSQL I can see my insert query and even COMMIT right after it)

This can be seen in API. When I create the new object it returns me it's id, 2 seconds later I delete this object and I get the error that object with this id does not exist. The problem occurs randomly (sometimes more often and sometimes less often) only on production/testing environment (not local) and disappears after rebuilding (It comes back after 1-2 days of uptime).

Had someone a similar problem?

Comment: For debugging questions it'd be beneficial to include at least some kind of example of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202016/5762711). Generally, everything that is flushed will be temporarily stored into the database and will be persisted when a .commit() happens.