# SQLAlchemy - How to get object's UUID available before commit/update/query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, instantiation, uuid

I'm a noobie trying get primary model's primary UUID automatically instantiated before it's stored into DB, I would not like to commit objects into db just to get the UUID available.

The short snippets below are from the actual code I have.

I think I need to attach initialization into some SQLAlchemy hook, but I don't know which or how.

I have an UUID helper as follows

```
class GUID(TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.LargeBinary
    ...
```

the in the tables I use

```
class Row(Model,Base):
    __tablename__ = "Row"
    id = Column(GUID(), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    row_text = Column(Unicode, index=True)
    original_row_index = Column(Integer)
```

when I do this test:

```
def test_uuid():
    row_text = "Just a plain row." 
    irow = 0

    row = Row(row_text, irow)
    row.save()
    row.commit()

    if row.id == None:
        print ("row.id == None")
    else:
        print ("row.id set")

    row2 = Row(row_text, irow)
    row2.save()
    if row2.id == None:
        print ("row2.id == None")
    else:
        print ("row2.id set")
```

it prints

> ```
>     row.id set
>     row2.id == None
> ```

The Model class I use is as follows:

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self):
      pass

    def save(self):
        db = Db.instance()
        db.session.add(self)

    def commit(self):
        db = Db.instance()
        db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that your should use not `commit` method but `flush` method: [Difference between flush and commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201455/sqlalchemy-whats-the-difference-between-flush-and-commit).

Flush not store information into the hard disk but create all changes on primary key:

> Primary key attributes are populated immediately within the flush() process as they are generated and no call to commit() should be required

[Link to original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316952/sqlalchemy-flush-and-get-inserted-id)