# sqlalchemy (vesrion 1.4 !) - get last inserted id

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

How I can get the last inserted id?
Please, pay attention on the `sqlalchemy` version, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1316952/14190526) question isn't my case.

I tried:

```
async def foo(db_session: AsyncSession, login):
    r1 = await db_session.execute(statement=models_users.insert().values(login=login))
    r2 = await db_session.flush()
    # r3 = await db_session.fetchval(...)  # Error, no such method for async
    r4 = await db_session.commit()
    print(r2, r4, r1.fechone())  # None, None, None
    print(r1.lastrowid)  # 'AsyncAdapt_asyncpg_cursor' object has no attribute 'lastrowid'


SQLAlchemy        1.4.4
asyncpg           0.22.0
```

Comment: Is your question about the missing fetchval method? I don't think that's a thing in any sqlalchemy version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's support for the [lastrowid](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=lastrowid#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.lastrowid) depends on the underlying DB-API implementation, so it isn't safe to rely on this attribute.  However SQLAlchemy provides an [inserted_primary_key](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=lastrowid#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.inserted_primary_key) attribute on the `CursorResult` object which ought to be reliable.

The return value is a tuple of the primary key values for the inserted row.

This version of the code in the question:

```py
async def foo(db_session: AsyncSession, login):
    r1 = await db_session.execute(statement=models_users.insert().values(login=login))
    print(r1)
    print('Last pk', r1.inserted_primary_key)
    await db_session.flush()
    await db_session.commit()
```

Will produce output like this:

```
<sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult object at 0x7f0215966bb0>
Last pk (17,)
```